# Windows Server - Can child domains sync via the parent?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

Hi I’m still learning the in and outs of domain controllers and had a questions on how they sync

If I have three sites.

Site A - Parent domain hq.local

Site B - Child domain child.hq.local

Site C - Child domain child.hq.local

If the VPN between Site B and Site C goes down and there is no other path for Site B and Site C to connect to each other,

Can Site B and Site C use Site A’s parent DC to sync with each other?

Answer (score 0):

> Can Site B and Site C use Site A’s parent DC to sync with each other?

No.

Without getting into more specifics, the domain partition is replicated between domain controllers in the same domain, not between domain controllers in other domains in the forest.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ad/naming-contexts-and-partitions